# Как организовано кэширование в клиентах соцсетей?

Tags: ios, android, java, objective-c, кэширование

Всем добрый вечер!
В процессе написания приложения возникла необходимость кэширования определенной информации на устройстве, но для меня пока не понятен алгоритм такого кэширования!

То есть, например в приложении клиент ВК на андроид в режиме оффлайн я могу просмотреть довольно большое кол-во заранее просмотренной информации, например переписку, собственный профиль, некоторые фото, список друзей и т.д..

Я пытаюсь написать подобный клиент и меня интересует как это лучше организовать, может существуют готовые рекомендации или набор определенных правил, алгоритмов.

Буду рад вашей помощи!
Заранее всем большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По науке делается так:

1. Пишем сервис/фоновый поток который берет из сервера по расписанию необходимые данные и складывает их в SQLite базу. Этот же поток/сервис должен следить за размером кэша, авторизацией и проч. вещами. Наружу он практически не должен высовываться - тихо сидеть в фоне и подгружать данные по мере необходимости
2. Над SQLite базой организуем `ContentProvider` выдающий наружу интересующие нас поля
3. Сверху `ContentProvider`'а нахлобучиваем `CursorAdapter`, который в свою очередь отображает данные на кастомный `ListView`
4. Если сделать `ListView` по уму то можно его "научить" операциям pull-to-refresh - то есть при достижении донышка "дергать" фоновый поток и подгружать старые записи.

Answer (score 1):

В SQLite скидывать закэшированные данные (ну или просто в директорию складывать какую-нибудь), в случае отсутствия сети показывать эти данные.
И даже, если есть сеть, можно показывать эти данные, если они валидны.

К примеру, сделать, чтобы запросы возвращали помимо данных ещё и хэш данных, чтобы каждый раз всю ленту не грузить в случае, если хэш не изменился.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме метода, описанного выше, иногда применяют прямую сериализацию в файл: объект сохраняется в файл в формате json или xml, либо вообще используется бинарная сериализация. Последняя - самая быстрая (потому что не требует парсинга), но требует немало хлопот, если язык не поддерживает сериализацию объекта "как есть". В таком случае приходится делать описание необходимых свойств объекта и по очереди их складывать в файл, чтобы потом их ровно в таком же порядке прочитать в те же самые свойства, либо выдумывать собственные костыли по сохранению справочников и подобных сложных типов.
Также обычно приложению предоставляется механизм для сохранения данных (если делаете Телеграм - вам нужен IsolatedStorage), но он зачастую оказывается медленнее - где-то видел статью, что твиттер на виндофоне в результате плюнул на все и перешел на бинарную сериализацию, потому что все остальное по скорости было сопоставимо с прямым интернет-запросом. Там же писали, что использовали максимальное дробление данных по файлам, что позволяло подгружать данные только в том случае, если они нужны, что уменьшало оверхеды.
И последнее касательно твиттера - эта штука своим кэшем съела у меня 70мб памяти на андроиде. Если делаете реальный кеш - не забывайте удалять устаревшие записи.

Comment: Я бы не советовал так делать, ибо поиск затрудняется.
В SQLite поиск довольно шустрый.

В файлах обычно хранить можно настройки/транзакции/сейвы.